# Sublime Text Build System for Slim

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, slim-lang

If I type in the `CMD.exe`

```
slimrb -p SashaSlim.slim>SashaSlim.html
```

the contents of the my valid file, for example, `SashaSlim.slim` correct compiled into `SashaSlim.html`. But I can not make the build system for Sublime Text, which would do the same.

Example of my code:

```
{
    "path": "$file_path",
    "selector": "text.slim",
    "shell_cmd": "slimrb -p $file_name>$file_base_name.html",
}
```

When I run my build system, create *blank* file `SashaSlim.html` without the result of compiling.

Where I made a mistakes in my `.sublime-build` file?

Windows 10
Sublime Text Build 3114

Thanks.

Comment: It seems, problem is solved — https://gist.github.com/Kristinita/f49eca1aa44545b5fcacaceeb8eaaee4 .

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "cmd": ["slimrb"],
    "working_dir": "${file_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "text.slim",
    "quiet": true,
    "windows": {
        "cmd": ["slimrb", "-p", "--trace", "$file", "$file_base_name.html"],
        "shell": true
    }
}
```

Re: https://gist.github.com/Kristinita/f49eca1aa44545b5fcacaceeb8eaaee4